# Error installing R (3.1.0) package caret on Ubuntu 14.04.1 LTS

Tags: r, ubuntu, install.packages, r-caret

Trying to install package "caret" on R 3.1.0 (Ubuntu 14.04.01 LTS) and running into a build error.

```
> install.packages('caret')
```

[...]

```
* installing *source* package ‘BradleyTerry2’ ...
** package ‘BradleyTerry2’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
** R
** data
*** moving datasets to lazyload DB
** inst
** preparing package for lazy loading
Error : object ‘brglm’ is not exported by 'namespace:brglm'
ERROR: lazy loading failed for package ‘BradleyTerry2’
* removing ‘/home/br00t/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.1/BradleyTerry2’
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘BradleyTerry2’ had non-zero exit status
ERROR: dependency ‘BradleyTerry2’ is not available for package ‘caret’
* removing ‘/home/br00t/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.1/caret’
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘caret’ had non-zero exit status

The downloaded source packages are in
    ‘/tmp/Rtmp7pWmvr/downloaded_packages’
> sessionInfo()
R version 3.1.0 (2014-04-10)
Platform: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu (64-bit)

locale:
 [1] LC_CTYPE=en_CA.UTF-8       LC_NUMERIC=C               LC_TIME=en_CA.UTF-8        LC_COLLATE=en_CA.UTF-8    
 [5] LC_MONETARY=en_CA.UTF-8    LC_MESSAGES=en_CA.UTF-8    LC_PAPER=en_CA.UTF-8       LC_NAME=C                 
 [9] LC_ADDRESS=C               LC_TELEPHONE=C             LC_MEASUREMENT=en_CA.UTF-8 LC_IDENTIFICATION=C       

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] sp_1.0-16

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] grid_3.1.0      lattice_0.20-29 tools_3.1.0
```

Wasn't able to find anything helpful on the interwebs. Not sure if this is an issue with the BradleyTerry2 package or brglm... help?

Thanks,

br00t

Comment: Never mind was able to resolve the issue by manually installing brglm and BradletTerry2 packges then reattempting install of caret and it worked... could have sworn that didn't work last night but hey, I'll take it!

Comment: I was wrong, the package built, but will not load, still complaining that "Error : object ‘brglm’ is not exported by 'namespace:brglm'"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are running a version of the brglm package greater than 0.5-9, uninstall and install brglm package version 0.5-9

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get over the issue too by installing the dependencies. You may want to select your answer as the right one.

Comment: Unfortunately, just installing the dependencies did not fully resolve the issue for me. I realized that the BradleyTerry2 package attempts to import brglm from the brglm package. This function is exported in version 0.5-9 of brglm, but does not appear to be from version 0.6-1 onwards. In order to get caret to build AND load, I had to install version 0.5-9 of brglm

Comment: Good to know eventually it did work for you. And thanks for sharing the right answer.